# Power gain values at the microwave amplifier

Tags: amplifier, filter, gain, impedance-matching

I have generated graphs in AWR software for signal gains, G_A, G_max, G_P and G_T, respectively. The amplifier I am using is "HMC141". Unfortunately, the values that came out look like this:

[image]

When I add impedance matching at the output (marked "2" in the picture below), the gain values come out well below zero.

[image]

Is this possible?Is it possible for the gain values at the amplifiers to come out negative?  Is there an error somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: The impedance matching goes from the input to output; your 50 Ohm load is the output.

Comment: So output matching is not needed at all??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: What I mean is your impedance matching network should go from input to output: the input is the amplifier's output, and the output is the load. As it is now it only makes sense if the signal is going from the load to the amplifier's output. In short: reverse the network to have the same orientation as the input, but make sure it is calculated for the correct values, because for the input you had (possibly) different conditions.

Comment: Looks like a two port mixer with inputs on both sides matched as a 1.5GHz HPF and output in the middle.

Comment: @a concerned citizen is this how it should look like:https://imgur.com/u3ZiEc6?fbclid=IwAR2cdux4rPQcu44gK3hYF2oFtHWvAomHwQqCW27xW2Jkr0fHXjWTgTpWRo0

Comment: @tomaszkolodziejski No, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDgq1.png). Don't add spaces in the names, use `@<TAB>` to cycle between them.

Comment: Negative gain means the output is smaller than the input.